# Wcf netTcpBinding without Soap

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I wanted to ask is it possible to change format of message in netTcpBinding to not use Soap. I know it is possible with webHttpBindng but I want to know about netTcpBinding.

Comment: What format do you want to use?  JSON?  Something else?

Comment: some custom binary format maybe but generally just wanted to know is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My belief is that NetTcpBinding itself is SOAP based; however, one can create custom binding using TCP transport of WCF to implement something own.